# HP DL360 Gen9 - Boot from PCIe SSD?

Tags: hp, ssd

We've been using SATA (ADATA or Transcend 2,5" SSD's), but a much neater solution would be to use a PCIe SSD (M.2 SSD + PCIe adapter).

We've tried M.2 WD Green SSD's as wel as M.2 Kingston SSD's. Both to no avail. The interesting fact is, when I use an M.2 -> Sata adapter and an Sata -> USB adapter, it can actually boot fine.

When I use the above configuration (M.2->Sata->USB) boot-repair-disk has the option to repair the boot, but with the M.2->PCIe I do not get this option. Also see (http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jpKWMP8RMY/).

Before I throw this idea into the bin, I would like to know if the HP DL360 Gen9 has any chance of booting from a PCIe SSD and possibly why not.

SSD's used:

- WDS120G1G0B-00RC30
- SM2280S3G2/120g

Adapter used (they look oddly similiar):

- Lindy M.2 SSD to PCIe Adapter Card
- StarTech x4 PCI Express to M.2 PCIe SSD adapter

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the HP DL360 Gen9 and most likely other HP ProLiant servers suffer from the issue that they do not work with "B&M Key" M.2 SSD's.

These SSD's seem to use SATA or PCIe 2x (which aren't very well [supported/standardised](https://serverfault.com/questions/556265/force-renegotiation-of-pci-express-link-speed-x2-card-reverts-to-x1-width)).
I've actually used NVMe (PCIe 4x) SSD's, they seem to work very well!

The SSD actually shows up in the "HP Storage Management Utility" and as a boot option in UEFI.
I however, from memory recall that this didn't work on the HP MicroServer (cube server)

Comment: HP DL120 G7, seems to have the same BIOS as the G10 microserver. Samsung EVO 970 M.2 NVMe is visible in Ubuntu on DL120G7, but seems impossible to boot (shows as unknown pcie device, but "Other storage media" in boot option.