# HP ProLiant ML310e G8 v2 ssd

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array

I have a `HP ProLiant ML310e G8 v2 with Intel® Xeon® E3-1220v3 3.10GHz` processor and I'd like to upgrade the storage to a SSD one.

Currently I have two Non-SSD hard drives that I've configured `RAID 1` and I'd like to create a separate `RAID 1` but with SSDs.

What kind of SSDs should I take:

1. `2 x Solid State Drive (SSD) Intel 540s Series, 1.0TB, M.2 80mm, SATA III`
2. `2 x Solid State Drive (SSD) Intel 540s Series, 1.0TB, 2.5'', SATA III`
3. `2 x Solid State Drive (SSD) Samsung MZ-7KE1T0BW, 2.5", 1TB, SATA III`

I'm not sure if the `HP ProLiant ML310e G8 v2` is compatible with `Solid State Drive (SSD) Intel 540s Series, 1.0TB, M.2 80mm, SATA III`

Seen also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/562086/proliant-ml310e-gen8-smart-array-predicted-failure-issue-with-ssd) which faces some issues with SSD drive.

Comment: You maybe should consult your hardware vendor?

Comment: @Thomas: Yup, will do that too but I was interested to know if are there any others which met the same scenario like I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Raid Controller Model, in the manual of the Vendor will mention the type of disks it supports and if it can handle another RAID.

Comment: will check that as soon I get to the server, I don't have direct access right now. Thanks! ;)