# Offline firmware upgrade DL360 G7 & DL185 G5

Tags: hp-proliant, firmware

We have just received two used HP ProLiant servers for community use and I need advice on where to find offline firmware update ISOs like those from Dell repositories. (My background is Dell)

The ISO's are needed for the following:

- HP ProLiant DL360 G7 1u Server
- HP ProLiant DL185 G5 Storage Server

The servers were not delivered with support cds so I would appreciate all the help.

The servers are out of warranty and we have no support agreement with HPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***See this first:*** [HP plan to restrict access to ProLiant server firmware - consequences?](https://serverfault.com/questions/571933/hp-plan-to-restrict-access-to-proliant-server-firmware-consequences)

---

You would find the specific firmware ISO, called the [HP Support Pack for ProLiant](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/), at:

http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/

Ideally, you have at least one HP server or system that's less than 3 years old , because you do need a valid serial number to be able to access this. Or you could good around for a recent HP SPP ISO download.

The other option is to go to the support pages for the two server platforms you have and select the target OS. You'll be able to download OS-specific firmware for them, excluding the main system BIOS, which requires a valid warranty. However, since these are old systems (2010 and 2006, the BIOS release hasn't been updated in years):

**DL360 G7** - http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=4091411&lang=en&cc=us

[image]

**DL185 G5** - http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3579903&lang=en&cc=us

[image]