# HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8 v2 Not Detecting Hard Drives

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

I have tested several solutions but non of them cant detect my 2 hard drives 
(legacy mode , acpi and raid embended)

I have a 2 Dell-Seagate SAS Cheetah 15k,7 hard drives (ST3300657SS) (they are not brand new and was used on another server)

**The hard drives cant not be detect by the system on the boot.**

On the boot system tries with lights on a caddies to sync hard drives but ends with no lights.

Maybe its not compatible or i need licence to activate SAS? Jumpers?

@ewwhite

- *Is there an OS on these disks?* (i dont know... and i dont have nay other place to test)
- *Are these disks in HP drive carriers?*
- *What OS are you trying to use?* (Freebsd in the setup cant detect them eather)
- *Which RAID controller is installed?* (on this server its Dynamic Smart array B120i Raid )

**[THE FINAL SOLUTION](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03326739)** : PAGE 5 compatible only with Hot-plug SATA drives and SATA SSD bot SAS.

Comment: We're missing some information. Is there an OS on these disks? Are these disks in HP drive carriers? What OS are you trying to use? Which RAID controller is installed?

Comment: @ewwhite Is there an OS on these disks? (i dont know... and i dont have nay other place to test)
Are these disks in HP drive carriers? (yes, this ones http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v15/803906963_1/HDD-font-b-tray-b-font-651687-001-2-5-SAS-SATA-Hard-Disk-font-b.jpg )
What OS are you trying to use? (Freebsd in the setup cant detect them eather)
Which RAID controller is installed? (on this server its Dynamic Smart array B120i Raid )

Comment: Did you create a RAID array using F8 during the Smart Array controller initialization after powering the server on?

Comment: @ewwhite if you mean by pressing F8 to enter the Smart Storage Administrator and after add a array , i cant because there is no annasigned hard drives are detected or you mean while its booting after pressing a F8 message that boots a ILO4  ( a pictures http://share.pho.to/6nZAn )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the disks you're using are not HP drives and you're using a Gen8 ProLiant server, there's no guarantee that the disks will be recognized or will even work reliably.

Your best option is to use actual HP branded/supported drives in the server.

See: [Third-party SSD solutions in ProLiant Gen8 servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers?rq=1)

Comment: its a very sad ... its cost a lot of waste time... thanks for the answer , i will wait a little and accept your answer.

Comment: In previous work with HP equipment, I note that HP uses special firmware on its drives.  Thus preventing use of standard vanilla drives.

Comment: Drive firmware wasn't an issue on HP servers until the Gen8 ProLiants came out. And even then, some drives could be used, just with an added warning message at POST time. I think the issue here are the bootleg drive carriers that the OP is using. There's probably a solution here, but it will likely involve calling HP support.

Comment: sometimes i get those carries light was static amber, when i removed them while server is booted