# HP Proliant DL360 G6 Wont Detect SSD

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ssd

I have a hp Proliant DL360 G6

It has 4 hard drive slots and I have 2 Intel 80GB SSDs and 1 WD 160GB regular hard drive. I have tried the WD in all 4 slots and each time it detects it and boots right up into vmware so the slots arn't defective. But when I insert the 2 Intel SSDs the server doesn't see them on POST

Answer (score 2):

[You can't just toss any old SSD into an HP ProLiant server](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers)... So your Intel SSDs likely are incompatible with the Smart Array P410 array controller in the system.

You should provide any error messages as they appear during the controller initialization.

Upgrading the controller firmware *may* help... however, beyond that, you don't have any other options. Try the firmware upgrade and see how it goes...

Comment: is their specific non hp ssds that work?

Comment: @mike Yes, there are. Look at the questions on the right side of this page.