# Samsung SM863 SSD disk in HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9

Tags: hp-smart-array

Does anyone have any experience on using Samsung SSD disks in HP servers?
I am planning to buy the following:

- ProLiant DL380 Gen9 Xeon E5-2620 v3 (Disk controller: Smart Array P440ar with 2GB FBWC)
- 4x SAMSUNG SSD ENTERPRISE SM863 960GB S-ATA-6.0Gbps in RAID 5

Does it work?

Server specs:
http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=7528675#!tab=specs

SSD specs:
http://www.samsung.com/us/business/computing/solid-state-drives/MZ-7KM960E

Disk trays from ebay.com:
/itm/2-5-SFF-SAS-TRAY-CADDY-FOR-HP-G8-651687-001-300G-10K-653955-001-with-LABEL-/281711422960?ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:US:1123

Answer (score 1):

Don't use non-HP disks in HP Gen8 and Gen9 servers. It never works well, and you'll inevitably run into problems.

See: [Third-party SSD solutions in ProLiant Gen8 servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers/528989#528989) 
and of course: [Third-party SSD solutions in ProLiant Gen9 servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/661637/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen9-servers/661643#661643)

HP have a special version of this Samsung disk in that capacity available with carrier and HP firmware. I can help you acquire it for a good price at this point if you're in the US.

Comment: I bought the equipment above, and it still works with no problems (yet...)