# non-enterprise SSDs on HP servers

Tags: hp, ssd

I'm a beginner with configuration of server computers.

my company wants to upgrade one of the servers with SSD storage. the server is HP DL380 G8.

the hardware seller company which my company works with, suggested SAMSUNG EVO 840 which seems it is basically a SSD for laptop PCs.

now the question is whether this kind of SSDs work with this kind of servers as the seller says?

does it have reliable and good performance?

will it endure long enough comparing to HP SSDs which are very costlier?

Comment: 1) Why for **laptop** PCs? Also for Desktops, Macs etc etc.Lets just call it 'non-enterprise'.
2) For this specific model: Data retention as already posted by @shodanshok.
3) Single JBOD? No redundancy? Or in an array (an which case: TRIM?).
4) What are you trying to do. Add a SSD and do not connect it is perfectly fine.  But you probably have a goal. What is it? Random access. Temp storage for a dev anvironments DB tables? ...

Comment: "the hardware seller company which my company works with" are IDIOTS and would be reprimanded by HP if they found out - use HP disks please.

Answer (score 1):

The 840 EVOs have very [significant problems with data retention](http://www.anandtech.com/SearchResults?q=840%20evo)

Non-enterprise SSDs can be fine, but you need to carefully pick the right ones. My suggestions are about Micron M550/M600/MX200 or Intel 730 series.

Comment: None of which will work in a Gen8 HP.

Comment: Oh, it is unfortunate. Why they do not work? The controller refuse to recognize them?

Comment: Controller, drive carrier, etc. you really should not use 3rd party disks with HP systems.

Comment: But HP's SSD are very expensive. Assuming that one have the correct drive carrier, will the controller refuse to initialize non-HP branded disk?

Comment: Sometimes, yes: http://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers

Comment: Many thanks for your link. This is very annoing: users should decide what storage to buy, not HP. A warning during POST is fine, but if it is _not only a warning_ and it cause specific problems (eg: unmanageable disks, array status as degraded, etc) it become a very bad thing. For the record, even DELL's popular H700 RAID card started with NO support for 3d party disk (they were not recognized), but after **much** user complains the situation changed: at first the disks were recognized but the array was marked degraded, then (with another FW upgrade) 3d party disk were fully supported.

Comment: It just depends on the disk. But I think more effort should be spent finding inexpensive SAS SSDs instead of using consumer SATA devices. You can also find HP SSDs on discount, but I prefer PCIe SSDs instead.