# Third-Party SAS SSD firmware HP Proliant G7

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array, sas

Is it possible to update the firmware of the third-party manufacture (SanDisk PN1-LB206M (B)) that makes the OEM SSD's for HP?

To HP's current [firmware](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5212940&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=54) for the exact same drive?

- HP Part #632633-001, SanDisk PN-LB206M (B)

If firmware is not update-able to HP's, will there be any compatibility, or performance lost comparable to the the non HP firmware drive?

Current Config:

- DL360 G7
- P410i 1GB FBWC
- 144GB memory
- SAS HDD's

Looking to switch over the HDD's to SSD (**not** interested in SATA solutions)

The closest post I could find here on server fault "[Third-party SSD solutions in ProLiant Gen8 servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers?answertab=votes#tab-top)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to make any firmware changes to the SanDisk/Pliant Lightning drive you have.

It *may* work in the server, but remember that these drives aren't great performers. You should try to find the HP version if you really need the compatibility. They're cheap on the used market now.

If the drive works, you'll also miss the HP wearout/endurance reporting and alarms.

Comment: I've read a bunch of your post. I'm glad you were able to weigh in on the features that would be missed by not using the HP OEM firmware drives.