# HP DL380p Fans run 100% as soon as OS Loads

Tags: hp-proliant, cooling

Sounds like a 747 taking off.  I have 2 exactly the same, bought used. Has P420i RAID controller, 64GB RAM, 3 500GB SSD, each in its own RAID0 array, and 2 - 2TB Seagate Firecuda hybrid drives in RAID1.  Fans run quietly after startup while posting, while in any BIOS or provisioning screen, no matter how long it runs.  Stays cool and quite until an OS (Win 2012r2 or CentOS 7) loads.  Then, no matter what is going on on server, fans run at 100%.  BIOS is set for "Optimal Cooling"

I have googled this and seen issues with fans, also 420i RAID controller runs hot, but I've found nothing on fans spinning up to 100% and staying there while all temperatures are well below cation threshold.

I can leave provision screen up for hours and servers run quietly. Then load OS, component temps don't change, but fans immediately spin to and stay at 100%. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because you're using non-HP disks in the server.
What make/model are the SSDs installed in the system?

[*Don't do that.*](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers/528989#528989)

I'm also assuming that you don't have the HP management agents loaded inside of the OS. It would make sense to add those since they help manage communication between the OS and ILO, which handles thermal management.

Comment: Thanks, ewwhite.  After reading your link, I replaced the hybrid drives with Seagate SATA III and the fan issue went away.  Do you have a link for HP management agents? I would +1 but I don't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: @jerryrig would you mind "accepting" this answer so this question gets resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Check your system firmware. This is likely an ACPI related issue, and since you've effectively eliminated OS-specific ACPI issues you're down to firmware.

If you're not running the latest firmware, try upgrading to the latest you can download from HP. If you're at the highest version already, could you post that version number? This issue might be addressed in their documentation.

Comment: In retrospect, this will almost never be the case. However, I have seen this issue "fixed" in some firmware updates that add compatibility for other hardware. If completely stumped on the cause, it may be worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with 4 x Dl380P G8 [ 2nd hand] 
Had installed 32 Samsung SSD drives.
Never had same issue with G7 and Samsung SSD.
The fix to overcome the HP imposed issue was to modify the fan array, the 6 fans.
The Red wire to fan, cut and installed 2 x 22 Ohm 5W resistors in parallel but in series with the red wire supply.

As they stick a bit you modify the frame to allow for it.
Very neat and professional modification.

The mod reduced noise like 4 aircraft taking off.
Reduced to 57.5 decimal, speech level. 
Ran for weeks internally for thermal checking.
No issues detected.

Works fantastic.  Excellent.

Comment: That's crazy :)

Comment: What happens when you actually need the fans to cool the server?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out to the 10G NICs we bought from HP were incompatible with the model.  Removing them resolved the issue.