# 3rd party SSD on DL360e Gen8 V2

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array

I want to order a HPE DL360e Gen8 V2 server, without any drives. I have read some topics regarding "unsupported" SSDs drives.

We want to use 1TB SSD drives.

Has someone tested and successfully installed 3rd party SSD drives on this server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which SATA controller you are using, which access protocols are supported and which backplane type you are trying to order.

Comment: i just want exactly order this server without any raid controller,  its work on SATA SSD ? 
           https://www.bargainhardware.co.uk/hp-proliant-dl360e-gen8-8-sff-configure-to-order

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to my post here:
[Third-party SSD solutions in ProLiant Gen8 servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/528875/third-party-ssd-solutions-in-proliant-gen8-servers/528989#528989)

This all depends on which Smart Array RAID controller is in the system, and what drive cage option you have (4 x 2.5" or 2 x 3.5").

Do you have the specific model of the server you're planning to purchase?

I can say that I'm happy with most SAS SSDs on Gen8 controllers as long as you use quality carriers.

Comment: Hi , its 8 x Small Form Factor (2.5") SFF Hard Drive Bays (Standard)                             i want order this server without any raid controller i want using onboard raid controller b120i , its will work with SSD Crucial MX500 OR Samsung 860 EVO ?