# ML350p Gen8 with non HP SSD

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd

I have a HP ML350p Gen8 which I am looking to upgrade.  I have seen this Kingston data centre SSD:

DC500 2.5" Enterprise SSD - 6GBps SATA SSD for Read-Centric and Mixed-Use Drives
https://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/dc500-data-center-solid-state-drive?Model=Read-Centric&Capacity=960GB

Though this should work (with the right SFF caddy) I have seen old (4yrs+) posts where the fans go into a high speed mode if they detect non HP drives as the temperature can't be checked.  Is this still an issue?  I can't find any HP SSD compatibility checker.

Answer (score 0):

You could check on [HP QuickSpec](http://h41370.www4.hpe.com/quickspecs/overview.html) but from my undertsanding you are correct, there is no online compatibility checker and yes the issue you seen is still there from what I heard. There is a good answer on that [there](https://serverfault.com/a/528989/256639).

For your question the real answer is to ask a HP reseller.

In my shop our HP reseller got inside contact at HP, and it's not uncommon to ask them for supported drives. I dont know why HP never did a compatibility checker, maybe it's to force the enduser to call their HP reseller, but as it's now, you dont have much choice. For a server not in production and that you don't mind the noise, you have the choice, but if in production I would not take that guess if it's supported or not.

Comment: Thanks - yes i read that link, had hoped things had moved on and HP was less protective.  Looks like it is take the risk and if it goes wrong hope the seller allow returns...

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I purchased a 960 GB Intel D3 S4510 2.5" Enterprise SSD

Worked fine in an ML350p Gen8 - all fans working normally and no complaint from the server.